# php foreach just looping on one value of array

Tags: php, foreach

Here is my code:

```
$bag3 = 7;
$row = 4;
$nom = 1;
$arr = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
while ($bag3){
while ($nom <= $bag3){
    echo $ay." ".$row;
    $nom++;
    $row++;
}if ($nom == $bag3){
    $nom = 1;
}
}
```

and here's the output:

```
red 4red 5red 6red 7red 8red 9red 10
```

I want it to loop through all the array values: `red`, `green`, `blue`, and `yellow`.
like this:

```
red 4red 5red 6red 7red 8red 9red 10green 11green 12green 13green 14green 15green 16green 17blue 18blue 19blue 20blue 21blue 22blue 23blue 24yellow 25yellow 26yellow 27yellow 28yellow 29yellow 30yellow 31
```

What should I change in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your code with a `foreach` loop over the array and a `for` loop for `$nom` from 1 to `$bag3`:

```
$bag3 = 7;
$row = 4;
$arr = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
foreach ($arr as $ay) {
    for ($nom = 1; $nom <= $bag3; $nom++, $row++){
        echo $ay." ".$row;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
red 4red 5red 6red 7red 8red 9red 10green 11green 12green 13green 14green 15green 16green 17blue 18blue 19blue 20blue 21blue 22blue 23blue 24yellow 25yellow 26yellow 27yellow 28yellow 29yellow 30yellow 31
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/NL7gj)

Comment: That is one wicked/tricky looping there Nick. I'm curious though, does it always end on an integer but no repeating text after? As you might have noticed, arrays and me don't make best of friends.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner it's probably more clear with newlines in the output (https://3v4l.org/EBaud), but yeah, it will always finish with a `$row` value which is going to be an integer.