# PHP : Making multiple loop of for and foreach

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach

This is continuation of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59098281/php-foreach-just-looping-on-one-value-of-array).

I have this code :

```
$bag3 = 7;
$row = 4;
$arr = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
foreach ($arr as $ay) {
    for ($nom = 1; $nom <= $bag3; $nom++, $row++){
    }
    $m1 = ($row - $bag3) + 1;
    echo "->mergeCells('A".$m1.":A".$row."')"."\n";
    for ($nom = 1; $nom <= $bag3; $nom++, $row++){
        $satu = ($row - $bag3) + 1;
        echo "->setCellValue(A".$satu.",".$ay.")"."\n";
    }
    $dua = $satu + 1;
    echo "->setCellValue(A".$dua.",".$ay.")"."\n";
}
```

And its output:

```
->mergeCells('A5:A11')
->setCellValue('A5',red)
->setCellValue('A6',red)
->setCellValue('A7',red)
->setCellValue('A8',red)
->setCellValue('A9',red)
->setCellValue('A10',red)
->setCellValue('A11',red)
->setCellValue('A12',red)
->mergeCells('A19:A25')
->setCellValue('A19',green)
->setCellValue('A20',green)
->setCellValue('A21',green)
->setCellValue('A22',green)
->setCellValue('A23',green)
->setCellValue('A24',green)
->setCellValue('A25',green)
->setCellValue('A26',green)
->mergeCells('A33:A39')
->setCellValue('A33',blue)
->setCellValue('A34',blue)
->setCellValue('A35',blue)
->setCellValue('A36',blue)
->setCellValue('A37',blue)
->setCellValue('A38',blue)
->setCellValue('A39',blue)
->setCellValue('A40',blue)
->mergeCells('A47:A53')
->setCellValue('A47',yellow)
->setCellValue('A48',yellow)
->setCellValue('A49',yellow)
->setCellValue('A50',yellow)
->setCellValue('A51',yellow)
->setCellValue('A52',yellow)
->setCellValue('A53',yellow)
->setCellValue('A54',yellow)
```

you see, from the second "Merge cell" `$satu` value become like `($dua + 7)`.
but what I wanted is the second `$m1 = $dua + 1` and so the third and fourth, and value of `$satu` after "merge cell" start from `($dua + 1)`.

I have asked to my senior, but he seems as confused as me.
So, what should I change in my code?
Thanks and sorry for the bad English.

Comment: Do you really want 8 `setCellValue` for each `mergeCells`?

Comment: @Nick yes, but actually there is seven setCellValue with value "A" and one setCellValue with value "B". so from A5 to A11 have "A" value and A12 have "B" value

Comment: Your current code has them all with `A`, what values do you want for the `B`? I can adjust my answer to suit.

Comment: @Nick the value take from an array, just like "A" take from array $arr.

Comment: So what exactly would the `setCellValue` look like? `setCellValue('B12',red)`? or something else? I can't modify the answer without knowing that...

Comment: @Nick lets use an example array : `$gab = array("der", "neerg", "uelb", "wolley");`. so it would be like : `setCellValue('A12',der)`, `setCellValue('A19',neerg)`, setCellValue('A26',uelb), and setCellValue('A33',wolley)

Comment: Something like this? https://3v4l.org/Ou0nY

Comment: @Nick Yes! just like that. thanks nick, you save my day.

Comment: Ok, I'll update the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with the empty `for` loop, which is causing `$row` to increment by 14 through each outer loop, where you only want it to increment by 7. You can fix that by removing that loop and then adjusting the values in the `mergeCells` and `setCellValue` output strings. You can add the `setCellValue` from the second array by using the key from the first one to index into it:

```
$bag3 = 7;
$row = 4;
$arr = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
$gab = array("der", "neerg", "uelb", "wolley");
foreach ($arr as $key => $ay) {
    echo "->mergeCells('A" . ($row + 1) . ":A" . ($row + $bag3) . "')" . "\n";
    for ($nom = 1; $nom <= $bag3; $nom++){
        echo "->setCellValue('A" . ++$row . "','$ay')" . "\n";
    }
    echo "->setCellValue('A" . ++$row . "','{$gab[$key]}')" . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
->mergeCells('A5:A11')
->setCellValue('A5','red')
->setCellValue('A6','red')
->setCellValue('A7','red')
->setCellValue('A8','red')
->setCellValue('A9','red')
->setCellValue('A10','red')
->setCellValue('A11','red')
->setCellValue('A12','der')
->mergeCells('A13:A19')
->setCellValue('A13','green')
->setCellValue('A14','green')
->setCellValue('A15','green')
->setCellValue('A16','green')
->setCellValue('A17','green')
->setCellValue('A18','green')
->setCellValue('A19','green')
->setCellValue('A20','neerg')
->mergeCells('A21:A27')
->setCellValue('A21','blue')
->setCellValue('A22','blue')
->setCellValue('A23','blue')
->setCellValue('A24','blue')
->setCellValue('A25','blue')
->setCellValue('A26','blue')
->setCellValue('A27','blue')
->setCellValue('A28','uelb')
->mergeCells('A29:A35')
->setCellValue('A29','yellow')
->setCellValue('A30','yellow')
->setCellValue('A31','yellow')
->setCellValue('A32','yellow')
->setCellValue('A33','yellow')
->setCellValue('A34','yellow')
->setCellValue('A35','yellow')
->setCellValue('A36','wolley')
```

Note that you may want to output the `$ay` and `$gab` values inside quotes as well using

```
echo "->setCellValue('A" . ++$row . "','$ay')" . "\n";
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Ou0nY)

Comment: what if i use mysql_fetch_array for array

Comment: What does the array look like if you do?